# Appending a string to the URL using a form

Tags: python, html, django, visual-studio-code

This is my form:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %} 
<input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
<input type="submit">
```

How can I append a word after the last character of the next link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/saturday/
```

Comment: Uhh, what exactly do you mean? Do you mean when you submit the form you want the url to be like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/saturday/?q=whatever-you-specified`? Your form's `method` is wrong if that is what you want.

Comment: if you are just wanting to add sth to the end of that string, it's as simple as: ```s = http://127.0.0.1:8000/saturday/"
s = s + "hello world"
print(s)```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello world

Comment: Thank you for your support but I made it by the way below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I made it by this way via django:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

if request.method=="POST": 
        try:   
            title = request.POST.get("q")
            return redirect(f'/wiki/{title}')
```